# ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'contents' of type blob cannot be null

Tags: mysql

I am not able to update the blob column ('contents') in mysql 8.0.28

`update file_attachment SET contents = load_file('/tmp/dmart.png') WHERE file_id = 1;`

the error am getting is

`ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'contents' cannot be null.`

The script to create the table is

```
CREATE TABLE `file_attachment` (
  `file_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `size` double(255,3) NOT NULL,
  `contents` longblob NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_modified_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```
mysql> show variables like 'secure_file_priv'; 
+------------------+-----------------------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+------------------+-----------------------+ 
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ | 
+------------------+-----------------------+ 
1 row in set (0.19 sec)
```

Comment: Please include info about how your table `file_attachment` is created (use [edit] to add the info from `SHOW CREATE TABLE file_attachment\G`)

Comment: Please also add the output from `show variables like 'secure_file_priv';`  (see: [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv))

Comment: The error is because you defined the column as `contents longblob NOT NULL`. This can be solved by deleting the `NOT`, but this will not help.  NULL is returned from [LOAD_FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) when an error occurs because the file is not found, or when `secure_file_priv` is set to another directory then you use now.

Comment: @Luuk here is the output of the command  : /var/lib/mysql-files/

Comment: @Luuk, the record already hold an image i want to update the record with new image.

Comment: Read the docs about [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv)